# Get sum of a column by date range

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a small line of code that will get the sum of a column

```
<?php

 class ManageServices{

 function getTotalSumByDateRange()
 {
    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as sum_of_date_range FROM services ");      

    $rowcount = $query->rowCount();

    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    return $result; 
}
}

?>
```

//search.php

```
<?php
 include_once('../../classes/class.ManageServices.php');
 $init = new ManageServices();  
 $sum_of_date_range = $init->getTotalSumByDateRange();    
 ?>
```

//search1

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
include_once('../../classes/class.ManageServices.php');
$init = new ManageServices();  
$date_from =$_POST['to_date'];
$date_to =$_POST['from_date'];

if(empty($_POST['to_date']) && empty($_POST['from_date']))
{
    $error = "No search query";
}
elseif(empty($_POST['to_date']) && !empty($_POST['from_date']))
{
     $error ="Please specify your start date search";
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['to_date']) && empty($_POST['from_date']))
{
     $error ="Please specify your end date search";
}
else
{
    $total_by_date_range = 0;
    $total_by_date_range = $init->getSumByDateRange($date_from, $date_to);
}
}

 ?>
```

//html

```
<?php
include_once('../../libs/search/search_sales_by_date.php');
include_once('../../libs/search1/total_sales.php');
?>

<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>search by dates</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<?php
if(isset($error))
{
  echo $error;
}
?>
</div>
<h3>Search Sales</h3>
<p>From</p>
<form method="POST" action="search_sales_by_dates.php">
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="from_date" id="field1"></p>
<p>To</p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="to_date" id="field2"></p><br />
<input type="submit" value="search" name="submit" id="submitdata">
</form>
<div id ="fillmein1">
<?php foreach($sum_of_date_range as $sum): ?>
  <td>Total Sales<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" aria-hidden="true"></span><?php echo     number_format($sum['total_sum'],2); ?></td>  
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
 <input type="hidden" value ="$total_by_date_range['sum_of_date_range'] ">//this is the problem
 </body>
 </html>
```

and in my table i have columns 'id','amount',date_of_service'.The query above will calculate all the 'amount' values and display in html, however, i want to add another query that will only get the sum of 'amount' column base on a date range input from html form.Any ideas on this?
Update..I think I'm almost there,after I updated search1.php,search.php,and html my problem now is I want to show the $total_by_date_range in same form.But when I submit the form, it shows no error but will not show the $total_by_date_range.anyway,the $sum_of_date range shows result in the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add another function:

```
class ManageServices {
  function getTotalSumByDateRange() {
     $query = $this->link->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as sum_of_date_range FROM services ");      
     $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
     $result = $query->fetchAll();
     return $result; 
  }
  function getSumByDateRange($date_from, $date_to) {
     $query = $this->link->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as sum_of_date_range FROM services where
     date_of_service between '".$date_from."' and '".$date_to."'");      
     $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
     $result = $query->fetch();
     return $result; 
  }
}
```

Search.php

```
<?php
 include_once('../../classes/class.ManageServices.php');
 $init = new ManageServices();  
 $sum_of_date_range = $init->getTotalSumByDateRange();
 $total_by_date_range = $init->getSumByDateRange($_POST['from_date'],$_POST['to_date']); 
?>
```

HTML

```
<?php
include_once('../../libs/search/search_sales_by_date.php');
?>

<div>
<?php foreach($sum_of_date_range as $sum):?> 
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" aria-hidden="true"></span><?php echo    number_format($sum['sum_of_date_range'],2); ?></td>  
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php
  echo "Total by date range: ".$total_by_date_range;
?>
</div>
```

You can try something like this.

Comment: I tried your code and i got notice message " Notice: Undefined variable: total_by_date_range in C:\wamp\www\php_oop\forms\search\search_sales_by_dates.php on line 59"...and I modified search.php to"<?php
{
   include_once('../../classes/class.ManageServices.php');
   
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
   $init = new ManageServices();
   $date_from = $_POST['from_date'];
   $date_to = $_POST['to_date'];   
        $total_by_date_range = $init->getSumByDateRange($date_from, $date_to);
   }
   else
   {
        $error = "Your search is not valid";
   }
  
}
?> and still got the notice..

Comment: Try to declare the varible before use it.

Comment: i tried to declare $total_by_date_range = 0 in search php, the warning notice is gone but it give me a result of zero,Also I tried var_dump($total_by_date_range) it give a result 0f 'Int 0',var_export($total_by_date_range) it give me a result of '0';

Comment: I already updated my code above, And I think i'm almost there, my problem is that variable $total_by_dat-range will not show up.What I want is that the result will display in the same page after submitting the form

Comment: Try with: <input type="hidden" value ="<?php echo $total_by_date_range['sum_of_date_range']; ?> ">//this is the problem

Comment: still not working.both var_dump and var_export return 'null'.What does it means?

Comment: If you run the code with hard values directly in the data bese, what value do you get?

Comment: i tried select sum(amount) as total_of_date_range from services where date_of_service between '2014-11-06' and '2014-11-07'; from the mysql console and it works.i notice also that in my form, the date format is 2014/11/06 where as in mysql the format is 2014-11-06

Comment: If you try between '2014/11/06' and '2014/11/07' you get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

First, when from date and end date is not specified, you display all the sum. But if those exists you filter your query to display sum within the date range.

Here is my solution.

```
function getTotalSumByDateRange($fromDate = "", $toDate = "")
{
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(amount) as sum_of_date_range FROM services ";      

    if (!empty($fromDate) && !empty($toDate) {
       $sql .= "WHERE date_of_service BETWEEN '". $fromDate . "' AND '" . $toDate . "'";
    }

    $query = $this->link->query($sql);

    $rowcount = $query->rowCount();

    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    return $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working.I rewrite my search.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
include_once('../../classes/class.ManageServices.php');
$init = new ManageServices();  
$date_to =$_REQUEST['to_date'];
$date_from =$_REQUEST['from_date'];

if(empty($date_from) && empty($date_to))
{
    $error = "No search query";

}
elseif(empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to))
{
    $error = "Specify your end date search";
}
elseif(!empty($date_from) && empty($date_to))
{
    $error ="Specify your start date search";
}
else
{
    if($date_from < $date_to)
    {
    $total_by_date_range = $init->getSumByDateRange($date_from, $date_to);
    foreach ($total_by_date_range as $key) 
    {
    $success ="Your Total amount of sales from ". $date_from . ' ' . "To" . ' ' .$date_to . ' '   ."is". ' ' ."P" .number_format($key['sum_of_date_range'],2);
    }
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "You bitch, Start date should not greater than the end date on your search  query";
    }
 }
}
else
{
$error = "Because you are an idiot, the script contains some bugs that is why it can't run on the   browser!";
}

?>
```

and I also changed the date format of Jquery datepicker, similar to the format used by mysql,I found out that having different date format in html($_GET method) and the format used by mysql will result null in query.